# Converse of three parallel line theorem

Tags: geometry

The three parallel line theorem (arbitrary name) states that:

If three or more parallel lines are cut by two transversals, then they divide the transversals proportionally.

[image]

For example, if x, y, and z are parallel, then $\frac{AB}{DE} = \frac{BC}{EF}$.
However, I could not find out if the converse was true i.e. if $\frac{AB}{DE} = \frac{BC}{EF}$, does it follow that x, y, and z are parallel? How do you prove the converse, if it is true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It need not be true. For instance, consider three lines originating from a single point such that the angles between any two adjacent lines are equal. Then draw two parallel transversals passing through the three non-parallel lines. It’s quite intuitive that the proportionality will follow.